# How to query the latest 5 posts and sort them by title?

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, get-posts

I'm looking to draw a menu listing of the latest "n" number posts, where the number "n" will be a user defined setting stored as an option.

n = 5; //Pull the latest 5 posts from the database.

The script I'm currently using (below) pulls all of the posts from the database and then only displays the latest 5 out of that collection.

This works fine until I decided to sort the list by title. When I do that, rather than sort the latest 5 posts by title, its sorting the entire collection of posts, without regard to when they were posted

Any tips on how I can change this query to only pull the latest "n" posts, then sort by title of those 5 only.

(**Note**: I'm really interested in the get_posts() query inside the UL element. The first query ($myquery) is just here to make sure we have posts to display before proceeding.)

```
function recent_posts(){
    $catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden');
    $myquery = new WP_Query();
    $myquery->query(array('cat' => "-$catHidden",'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')));
    $myrecentpostscount = $myquery->found_posts;
    if ($myrecentpostscount > 0){ ?>
    <ul>
    <?php 
    global $post;
    if(get_option('mySort') == 'asc'){
        $sortOrder='title';$sortDirection='asc';
    }
    $myrecentposts = get_posts
    (
        array
        (
            'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
            'cat' => "-$catHidden",
            'numberposts' => get_option('cb2_latest_count'),
            'orderby' => $sortOrder,
            'order' => $sortDirection
        )
    );

    foreach($myrecentposts as  $idxrecent=>$post) { 
        //DRAW THE POST MENU
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: I think the crux of the problem is that there does not appear to be a way to call just the latest 5 posts, then sort only those by title. When I apply a sort to the query, rather than first pulling the latest 5 posts and sorting those, it sorts on the entire collection of posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$yourquery = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&orderby=title');` would do that.

---

**Edit** *Added Answer*

```
<?php 
$posts = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');
foreach($posts->posts as $post){
    $sorted[$post->ID] =  $post->post_title;
}
asort($sorted, SORT_STRING);

foreach($sorted as $k=>$v){
        //your loop -- use ID's for each item call
    the_title($k);
    the_content($k);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer MF, but I'm not quite there yet. I think what might be confusing is that I'm really concerned with the 2nd query, get_posts(). Its still pulling from the entire collection of posts, not the *latest* 5

Comment: what don't you get them, then order them? If your problem is getting the wrong ones, get the right ones first, then put them in order.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do. However, Once you have the latest 5 posts, they are in post order (latest first). I want to then take those 5 posts and order them by alpha before writing them to the for loop. how do you then to the forloop what order to arrange them in?

Comment: this should do it. (see edit.)

Answer (score 0):

use the following code and modify to your liking:

```
// grab latest five posts
$latestposts = get_posts(); // by default latest 5 is grabbed
// just grab post ids
$keys = array_keys($latestposts);
// grab those 5 posts but ordered by title
$fivepostsorderedbytitle = get_posts(array('orderby' => 'post_title', 'post__in' => $keys));
```